# plot trajectory of multiple moving objects in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, path

I'm currently working on my final year project. The goal is to detect "normal" events in the parking lot environment (such as a person walking in a parking lot) using trajectory analysis. I have completed background subtraction and blob detection. I want to plot the trajectory of the moving object ( eg: human, car,etc) by using the co-ordinates of the centroids of the bounding boxes. is there a predefined function for doing this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll first have to TRACK the blobs, so you have to decide which blob is the same one as in the last frame. There are simple/limited ways to do this and more complicated/powerful ways to do it. Drawing a tracked trajectory is simple like Eni answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the X and Y pixel coordinates you can always use opencv's basic drawing library to draw a line that follows the path taking by the object. An example of this can be seen below.

```
    int iLastX = -1; 
    int iLastY = -1;

     Mat imgLines = Mat::zeros( imgTmp.size(), CV_8UC3 );;

        while(true){

            Mat imgOriginal;

             if (iLastX >= 0 && iLastY >= 0 && posX >= 0 && posY >= 0)
               {
                //Draw a red line from the previous point to the current point
                line(imgLines, Point(posX, posY), Point(iLastX, iLastY), Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
               }

                iLastX = posX;
               iLastY = posY;

      imgOriginal = imgOriginal + imgLines;
      imshow("Original", imgOriginal); //show the original image
        }
```

Comment: I tried implementing the above logic but I couldn't plot the trajectory. It only draws a line when there are two bounding rectangles of different blobs in the same frame. Once the frame is updated the line disappears. How can I plot a line between the current position of  the centroid of a blob and centroid of previous position of the same blob?

Comment: You have more than one blob on a frame. How are you deciding which blob to track and which to ignore. From the code perceptive any update to the blobs position (which in this case is a new blob )will be plotted on the screen. This leads to the first blob being viewed as the original position and the second blob the new position. Please try this with only a single blob and provide feedback. Further, if you want to plot the direction of multiple blobs simutanuesly you need to make changes to your code to help identify which blob is which

Comment: Also, the reason why the lines disappeared after each frame is probably because of your implementation I have edited the code to provide a more clear solution. You can also check out the link were the code is been used here:- http://opencv-srf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html

Comment: I followed the tutorial and it worked. Thank you very much Eni. :)

Comment: No probs, would appreciate it if you accept this answer as the right solution by clicking on the accept button next the the answer :)